# Hamcrest's greaterThan and lessThan doesn't compile in junit:junit:4.12

Tags: android, unit-testing, hamcrest

I can't compile greaterThan and lessThan in test section on my app by junit:junit:4.12

my code is:

```
 List<String> list = someListProducingMethod();
 assertThat("test",  containsString("estr"));
 assertThat(list, allOf(hasSize(greaterThan(3)), hasSize(lessThan(12))));
```

Answer (score 1):

> just add this line to gradle

```
testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
```